# ValueError: Namespace Xdp not available

Tags: python, gtk, gnome, flatpak

I want to import Xdp in the Gnome Builder python template called "GTK4 Application".

Adding this:

```
gi.require_version("Xdp", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Xdp
```

results into:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/bin/python-test", line 45, in <module>
    from python_test import main
  File "/app/share/python-test/python_test/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    gi.require_version("Xdp", "1.0")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 126, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Xdp not available
Application exited
```

The strange thing is that `require_version` does work for `Gtk` and `Adw` just not for `Xdp`

If I run the same code in a venv it works fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using flatpak?

Comment: Yes, I use flatpak. What I did was:
1. Create a new python "GTK4 Application"
2. Add the mentioned code to import Xdp
3. Hit run